# All my events sent to Google Analytics are undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up "goals" for Google Analytics on a client wordpress. I'm not a big fan of plugins etc but that's on what I have to work.

So the client wants to analyse his forms (made with Contact Form 7). Contact form 7 allows you to execute a script when the form is send.

Here is the script I use when the form is completed

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
ga('event', 'mail', {
  'event_category' : 'sent',
  'event_label' : 'test'
});
}, false);
```

In Google analytics I get the event but all values are "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events), the syntax for sending events is the following. There is a send command, and hit type is specified as a second argument, followed by event details.

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

So in your case you should use this code:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'sent', 'mail', 'test');
}, false);
```

Your current syntax is more similar to that of [GTAG version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events) of tracking, which is based on the `gtag()` object:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

Comment: To be fair Universal Analytics also allows to use a configuration object (does not detract from your point, though, since this would still require the "ga('send', 'event'" syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @Eike Pierstorff.